# Overlaying divs in flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a website layout using flexbox. Here's my previous question on how to do so:
[HTML 100% Height with multiple inline scrolling divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771182/html-100-height-with-multiple-inline-scrolling-divs)

Now I would like to modify the right column (container **H**): 
Instead of just one full height scrollable DIV as it is now, I need three layers one above each other, same size and position.
Container **H** should remain the one on the bottom, still taking up all the height and be scrollable.
The one in the middle (container **I**) should fill the page but not be scrollable.
The one on top (container **J**) should be as high as needed, but not exceed the page, and be scrollable if higher.

Any idea on how to do so?
I tried making the container relative and the divs absolute, but it totally breaks my layout.

CSS:

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        align-content: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    header {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        min-height: 84px;
        height: 175px;
        max-height: 175px;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }

        header #headerWrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
            background-color: magenta;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            header #headerWrapper nav {
                min-height: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                max-height: 40px;
                background-color: green;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            header #headerWrapper #toggleFilter {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                right: 195px;
                bottom: 0px;
                width: 16px;
                height: 38px;
                background-color: red;
            }

            header #headerWrapper #filterContainer {
                min-height: 44px;
                height: 135px;
                max-height: 135px;
                background-color: gray;
                flex: 1 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        header #clipboardContainer {
            width: 175px;
            height: 175px;
            background-color: blue;
            overflow: hidden;
            -webkit-transition: height 0.2s;
            -moz-transition: height 0.2s;
            -ms-transition: height 0.2s;
            -o-transition: height 0.2s;
            transition: height 0.2s;
        }

    header.filter-collapse #headerWrapper #toggleFilter {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        header.filter-compact {
            height: 84px;
            max-height: 84px;
        }

            header.filter-compact #headerWrapper #filterContainer {
                height: 44px;
                max-height: 44px;
            }

            header.filter-compact #clipboardContainer {
                height: 84px;
            }

                header.filter-compact #clipboardContainer:hover {
                    height: 175px;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0px;
                }

    #contentWrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        align-content: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
        overflow: auto;
    }

        #contentWrapper #contentLeftWrapper, #contentWrapper #contentRightWrapper {
            flex: 1 0 50%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #contentWrapper #contentLeftWrapper #contentLeftContainer, #contentWrapper #contentRightWrapper #contentRightContainer {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
        }

            #contentWrapper #contentLeftWrapper {
                background-color: red;
            }

            #contentWrapper #contentRightWrapper {
                background-color: aqua;
            }

            #contentWrapper #headerLeftContainer, #contentWrapper #headerRightContainer, #contentWrapper #footerLeftContainer {
                min-height: 33px;
                height: 33px;
                max-height: 33px;
            }

            #contentWrapper #contentLeftWrapper #contentLeftContainer, #contentWrapper #contentRightWrapper #contentRightContainer {
                overflow: auto;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<main>
    <div style="background: red;">
        A
    </div>

    <header class="filter-compact">
        <div id="headerWrapper">
            <nav>B</nav>
            <span id="toggleFilter"></span>
            <div id="filterContainer">
                C
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="clipboardContainer">D</div>
    </header>

    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div id="contentLeftWrapper">
            <div id="headerLeftContainer">E</div>
            <div id="contentLeftContainer" style="background-color: yellow;">
                F                </div>
            <div id="footerLeftContainer">G</div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentRightWrapper">
            <div id="headerRightContainer">H</div>
            <div id="contentRightContainer" style="background-color: yellow;">
                H                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/davidedesantis/mqmgad4w/

Since it's quite hard to understand, I have included two picture. The first shows how it is now:
[image]

And this is what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to include a drawing of what you're looking for. I've read your question twice and it's hard to understand.

Comment: You are right, it's really hard to understand. I have added some images.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to do this:

```
#contentWrapper #contentRightWrapper #contentRightContainer .popupI {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 154px);
    background: #05DD00;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#contentWrapper #contentRightWrapper #contentRightContainer .popupJ {
    position: fixed;
    background: #886CFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    max-height: calc(100% - 154px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/obeLzvdn/

Comment: Not exactly. It was hard to show in the image, but I and J have the same position as H, they are just on top of it (z-index). I tried using position: fixed (or absolute), but then it does not comply with the flexbox container.

Comment: You may adjust the measure of each calc() values. https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/nsyem048

Comment: Looks better now. Is there a way to do that without using calc? I used flexbox to have dynamic height and now with this, I would have to add fixed heights again.

Comment: Using ```calc()``` you can made it easy, but you need to consider that fixed elements are related to viewport.

Depending of case, you can use inner elements with ```position:absolute``` inside elements with ```position:relative```.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I just want to have 3 layers like H instead of just one. All above each other (via z-index) and all of them adhering to the flexbox.